# Envío string a C (Atmel Studio)

Tags: c, atmel

Mi intención es enviar a una placa Atmel una string desde una app android.

Éste es el código android:

```
try 
{
    // Server send data
    out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
    /*    out.println("apply," + cadena + "," + 1 + "," + "lala" + ",");*/

    //   out.print(cadenaEnviar);
    out.println("lele");

    Log.d(TAG, "C : Sent. Done");

}
```

Y éste es el código C de la placa donde está el escuchador (dentro del switch, la parte  `MSG_RECV`):

```
static void socket_cb(SOCKET sock, uint8_t u8Msg, void *pvMsg)
{
    switch (u8Msg) 
    {
        /* Socket bind */
        case SOCKET_MSG_BIND:
        {
            tstrSocketBindMsg *pstrBind = (tstrSocketBindMsg *)pvMsg;
            if (pstrBind && pstrBind->status == 0) 
            {
                listen(tcp_server_socket, 0);
            } 
            else
            {
                printf("socket_cb: bind error!\r\n");
                close(tcp_server_socket);
                tcp_server_socket = -1;
            }
        }
        break;

        /* Socket listen */
        case SOCKET_MSG_LISTEN:
        {
            tstrSocketListenMsg *pstrListen = (tstrSocketListenMsg *)pvMsg;
            if (pstrListen && pstrListen->status == 0) 
            {
                printf("socket_cb: Ready to listen.\r\n");
                accept(tcp_server_socket, NULL, NULL);
            } 
            else
            {
                printf("socket_cb: listen error!\r\n");
                close(tcp_server_socket);
                tcp_server_socket = -1;
            }
        }
        break;

        /* Connect accept */
        case SOCKET_MSG_ACCEPT:
        {
            tstrSocketAcceptMsg *pstrAccept = (tstrSocketAcceptMsg *)pvMsg;
            if (pstrAccept) 
            {
                accept(tcp_server_socket, NULL, NULL);
                tcp_client_socket = pstrAccept->sock;
                printf("socket_cb: Client socket is created.\r\n");
                recv(tcp_client_socket, gau8SocketTestBuffer,   sizeof(gau8SocketTestBuffer), 0);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("socket_cb: accept error!\r\n");
                close(tcp_server_socket);
                tcp_server_socket = -1;
            }
        }
        break;

        **/* Message receive */
        case SOCKET_MSG_RECV:
        {
            tstrSocketRecvMsg *pstrRecv = (tstrSocketRecvMsg *)pvMsg;
            if (pstrRecv && pstrRecv->s16BufferSize > 0) 
            {
                char *p;
                p = (char *)pstrRecv->pu8Buffer;
                printf("CADENA ENVIADA:  %s.", (char *)p);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("socket_cb: recv error!\r\n");
                close(tcp_server_socket);
                tcp_server_socket = -1;
            }
            memset(gau8SocketTestBuffer, 0, sizeof(gau8SocketTestBuffer));
            recv(tcp_client_socket, gau8SocketTestBuffer, sizeof(gau8SocketTestBuffer), 0);**
        }
        break;

        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Cuando lo muestro a través del PuTTY, la cadena ha sido recibida con éxito, pero la salida es algo extraña, a continuación de la cadena enviada añade espacios, y un salto de línea...

Ejemplo:

Si mando "lele", llega lo siguiente (los guiones simbolizan los espacios):

"lele ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"

¿Alguna idea de lo que sucede?

Comment: Creo que tu problema se debe al tamaño del buffer de `Recv` o bien con el `Send` desde la app android. Asumo que posiblemente esta enviando bytes de más o que tienes una cantidad de bytes fija en el buffer.

Has intentado depurar o algo para conocer la longitud del mensaje? Si es así mira a ver si la longitud es siempre la misma.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta! te refieres a que compruebe su longitud en el propio C, o la longitud enviada desde java? alguna sugerencia si fuera en el recv? de trasladar esa cadena a otra con los caracteres ajustados?

Comment: Eso sería lo mas lógico en caso de que la cadena que recibes en el `PuTTY` sea del mismo tamaño en todos los casos, si envías el string desde android deberias observar el array de `byte` o el `string` que pasas por parametro en la funcion de  envio. De lo contrario, buscaría la forma de mover los caracteres a una variable ajustada.

Comment: desde android lo he mirado y esta bien enviada, por lo que es al recibirla cuando añade todo eso...no se por donde trirar